# Fixing height objects in input group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have input group with this structure:

```
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            Jesteś użytkownikiem<br /> tych urządzeń?
        </span>
        <span class="form-control">
            <input type="checkbox" checked data-bind="checked: MeUser">
        </span>
    </div>
```

As you can see `input-group-addon` consists of two lines and `form-control` only one line.
Therefor height of both object is not aligning. You can see this in [this Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/117581)

Can anyone suggest me modifications to make this two object to have same height?

Comment: Provide your fillde at jsFiddle

Comment: What's wrong with bootply if I'm using only bootstrap no external JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a static value to the input-group class

& set static values to the child classes

CSS:

```
.input-group{
height:100px;
}
.input-group-item{
height:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-item"><span class="input-group-addon">
        Jesteś użytkownikiem<br /> tych urządzeń?
    </span></div>
    <div class="input-group-item"><span class="form-control">
        <input type="checkbox" checked data-bind="checked: MeUser">
    </span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working, but I'm searching more generic. Setting height's in many input groups to fix sizes of object inside is something I'm trying to omit

Comment: (A small suggestion, why not add a <br /> at the end of the second span? lol)

I see what you mean, I'm just thinking it will be a different height because of the content, unless you made the content float/position or something, so that it rolls over the boundaries.